# Filter angular json 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm starting an angular application 7, beginner angular.
I'm making a call from an api (for example) and storing the result in localstorage. So far so good.
After saving I need to make a filter in the field called pdv.

I can not implement the filter the way it is, it says that the filter is not part of the viewers.
Can you give me a tip?

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

const CACHE_KEY = 'httpSalesCache';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  repos;

  constructor(http: HttpClient){

    const path = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/x';
    this.repos = http.get<any>(path)

    .pipe(map(data => data.items));

    this.repos.subscribe(next => {
      localStorage[CACHE_KEY] = JSON.stringify(next);
    });

    this.repos = this.repos.pipe(
      startWith(JSON.parse(localStorage[CACHE_KEY] || '[]'))
    ) 
  }
}
```

This is the return of the call http:

```
{"items":[
{"pdv": 1, 
    "status": "a"
}]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? What error are you getting? What is the expected correct result you want to see?

Comment: @hlfrmn Sorry for my English, but I wanted to do something like this.
.pipe (map (data => data.items) .filter (data.items.pdv === 1));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using TypeScript builtin `filter()` function. Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_filter.htm

```
const data = {
  "items": [
    {
      "pdv": 1,
      "status": "a"
    }]
};

const filterValue = 1;
const result = data.items.filter(element => {
  return element.pdv === filterValue;
});
```

`result` will contain an array of all `items` that contained the property `pdv` with a value of 1;

**EDIT**, updated after your comment

**EDIT 2** I realised you dont need a variable to store the result, you can just update the observable

```
filterValue = 1;

path = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/x';
this.repos = http.get<any>(path).pipe(
        map(data => { 
            data.items = data.items.filter(element => {
                return element.pdv === filterValue;
              });
        }));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a filter in this block?

.pipe (map (data => data.items));

In the current form that was implemented?

Comment: @lams If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as answered so other people know you have solved the issue.

Comment: I updated but an error occurred. Look:
Link image: https://ibb.co/HdxR7DB

Comment: my mocky http://www.mocky.io/v2/5bfea0d63100007000bb4d72
My code udated https://ibb.co/dprJw4T

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you trying to filter the result, and store the filtered result in localStorage?

Comment: So I need to make an app that works offline. I thought about storing all the records in localstorage and if necessary filtering the data offline.
If I have offline I will filter the data offline if not filter online.
I added to the sw project to help with the operation.
I want to filter the data after storing all the information. Filter only to view, keep all in localstorage.

Comment: Well the error says it's not valid JSON string. If you are having trouble with JSON you should mark this question as answered and post a new question.

Comment: Ok, tks @Teun van der Wijst